# I have an Acer nitro 5 AN515-51 with intel i5-7300HQ. I want to upgrade to nvme SSD as boot disk

Tags: ssd, nvme

I have an Acer nitro 5 AN515-51 with intel i5-7300HQ. There is an already installed 1TB HDD which is the primary boot device. I want to add an M.2 NVMe SSD to the laptop. My BIOS version is Insyde 1.13 26/12/2017 . I want to know if I can set a M.2 NVMe SSD as my boot device. I have seen that AN515-51 has support for NVMe storage. But is it bootable?

BIOS/Date: Insyde1.13/ 26-11-2017
SMBIOS version: 3.0
Intel chipset: HM175
BIOS mode: UEFI

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if I can set an M.2 NVMe SSD as my boot device. I have seen that AN515-51 has support for NVMe storage. But is it bootable?

Any system using the Intel chipset in question supports booting to NVMe devices.

Comment: I will try installing. Thanks.